# I add a dynamic property in qt designer .ui file, I want use property member function to get property

Tags: c++, qt

I add a dynamic property in .ui file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>test</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="test">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="function" stdset="0">
   <string notr="true">testCb</string>
  </property>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I want to get the property of function, but the `property` member function return value is invalid.

Here is code:

```
QString function = t.property("function").value<QString>();
```

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I want to add property in ui file not in cpp file.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. The designer file is static.

Comment: Not just static, it gets overridden every time

Comment: @lens I think there is another problem in question here. Could you share the underlying problem and why you think this is a solution?